# Creating PHP Bots for site maintenance

Tags: php

I have a PHP website in which, when a member visits a page, a series of database maintenance actions are made.

For example, in a common page, I've included a PHP script which checks how many posts *every user* has made and updates the database giving them points accordingly.

The problem with this method is that my website has 100+ members, and I'm worried that my scripts start to slow down as my memberbase grows.

Is there any way to code a bot in PHP, so my database can be updated without the user's intervention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should run a PHP file from within a `cron` job.  Most PHP hosts including shared hosting provide `cron` access.

With `cron` you can schedule a task to run on an interval basis.  This PHP program will then go through and do the updating that you require.  So... take the code you do now and move it into a seperate PHP file and then tell `cron` to run it maybe once an hour or whatever you deem to be the correct interval.

Comment: In addition to this advice - it makes sense to recalculate amount of posts done by user only for users that have posts newer than previous recalculation date

Comment: Whoa that was easier than expected! Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Create a cron to run daily (for instance) with the follow command:

```
php -q /home/cpaneluser/cron.php
```

And put a `cron.php` outside of `public_html` with all maintenance taks.

Or allow only administrators to do the maintenance tasks with a link in administrative panel.

Answer (score 2):

For best performance, you need to update users table when he publish the post, not every time when need to know how many posts he published.